# Initial value for type like [number, number]

Tags: typescript

I have a field which type is `[number, number]` and issues with TypeScript compiler (`strict` set to `true`) complaining about initial value. I've tried the following:

1. `public sheet: [number, number];` - throws `error TS2564: Property 'sheet' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`
2. `public sheet: [number, number] = [];` - throws `error TS2322: Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.`
3. `public sheet: [number, number] = [] as [number, number];` the same as above

I know I can create a little monster like `public sheet: [number, number] = [] as any as [number, number];` (or assign e.g. `[0, 0]` what I don't want to do) but I wonder is there a better way to go. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is comes from the compilerOption [`strictPropertyInitialization`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization) which strict mode enables.

You can use the *[definite assignment assertion modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization)* `!` to to tell typscript its initialised elsewhere:

`public sheet!: [number, number];`

Comment: This is very interesting. But even with this you can't assign sheet to an empty list, because it complains about types. `[number, number] | undefined[]` it seems to work for both cases, but i don't know if there's a better way.

Comment: In general TS is not going to be happy with initializing a value to a supertype with the intent that you'll make it match the type "later". There's not a straightforward way to convince it that `[]` is an acceptable value

Comment: Is it possible just to make it `[number, number] | undefined` instead?

If not, then sticking in the land of bizarre types `[number, number] | (number & void)[]` seems to work pretty well. Lets you assign only the tuple or `[]`, and always lets you treat each element out of it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and shortest way will be to convert the type after the assignment, as following:

```
const arrayOfNumbers = [] as any as [number, number];
```

The result of this will be that the type of `arrayOfNumbers` will be `[number, number]` as requested, but you will still get an empty array `[]` as initial value.

TypeScript won't let you assign anything else into this array but the given structure of `[number, nunber]` (if strict mode is enabled, of course).